# How to tell sqlsrv extension (php8.1-fpm) to accept self signed certificate?

Tags: sql-server, php-fpm, self-signed-certificate, moodle

I am currently encountering a problem on a Moodle server which uses an external MS SQL DB for its authentication and enrollments.

During connection, an error occurs related to a self-signed certificate.

Is there a way to force the certificate to be trusted via an option in the PHP extension? I installed sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv extensions on php8.1-fpm but I don't know which one is actuelly used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that via the php config, according to the documentation this is only a connection argument that can be set in the code.

It should however be sufficient to add the certificate as trusted in the OS certstore. Then php should accept it as well.

This has the added benefit that not every self signed certificate will be accepted but only this, reducing your attack surface.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you. Would you know how to add a self signed certificate on Linux? And maybe how to retrieve the public key of this certificate from a MS SQL server? I can't find how to do that.

Comment: Both tasks have been asked again and again and should be easy to find.

Comment: I added the certifcate and I don't get the self signed certificate error anymore. But now, I'm getting a subject name mismatch error ... It should'nt as it should be trusted.

Comment: That's to be expected, the name must match, that's unrelated from trusting or not trusting a certificate. You need a certificate with a matching name, either self signed or from a trusted CA.